# Why my log has been printed two times

Tags: python, class, logging

Why my log has been printed two times
I have three python files
When I call test2:
my log has been printed two times

```
2018-06-29 20:41:36,466 - test - INFO - 2222222222222222222
2018-06-29 20:41:36,466 - test - INFO - 2222222222222222222
```

I did not call the AAA method my_print.

handle_log.py

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import logging
import logging.handlers
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

        # #error日志发送邮件
        #
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, path='test',title=None):
        # 得到一个日志对象
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(path)
        # 修改默认级别
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        #将日志发送至邮件
        self.mail_log = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(('mail.test.com',123),'u2_dev_send@test.com','test@test.com',title,credentials=('test@test.com','test'),secure=None)
        self.mail_log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

        # 记录日志的文件和级别
        self.write_log = logging.FileHandler("all.log")
        self.write_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # 打印日志的到窗口上
        self.print_log = logging.StreamHandler()
        self.print_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

        # 设置日志格式
        formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
        self.write_log.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.print_log.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.mail_log.setFormatter(formatter)

        # 将相应的发送目的地添加到logger对象中
        self.logger.addHandler(self.write_log)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.print_log)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.mail_log)

    # def __del__(self):
    #     self.logger.removeHandler(self.write_log)
    #     self.logger.removeHandler(self.print_log)
    #     self.logger.removeHandler(self.mail_log)

    def debug(self, message):
        self.logger.debug(message)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.print_log)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.mail_log)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.write_log)

    def info(self, message):
        self.logger.info(message)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.print_log)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.mail_log)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.write_log)

    def war(self, message):
        self.logger.warning(message)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.print_log)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.mail_log)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.write_log)

    def error(self, message):
        self.logger.error(message)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.print_log)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.mail_log)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.write_log)

    def cri(self, message):
        self.logger.critical(message)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.print_log)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.mail_log)
        # self.logger.removeHandler(self.write_log)
```

---

test1.py

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
# sys.path.append('/data1/test/app_sem')
sys.path.append('/root/request2_python/')
from sem.handle_log import Logger


class AAAA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = Logger(title='bbbbbbbbbbb')
    def my_print(self):
        self.log.info('1111111111111111111111')



# a = AAAA()
# a.my_print()
```

---

test2.py

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
# sys.path.append('/data1/test/app_sem')
sys.path.append('/root/request2_python/')
from sem.handle_log import Logger
from sem.vivo.test1 import AAAA


class BBBB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.log_test2 = Logger(title='cccccccc')
    def my_print_b(self):
        self.log_test2.info('2222222222222222222')

b = BBBB()
a = AAAA()
# a.my_print()
b.my_print_b()
# b.my_print_b()
```

---

result:

```
2018-06-29 20:41:36,466 - test - INFO - 2222222222222222222
2018-06-29 20:41:36,466 - test - INFO - 2222222222222222222
```

Why has same log line printed twice?

Comment: It is because you create two handlers. Try to remove `a = AAAA()` and see results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your Logger do have the same name "test", so when you're sending a log message to "test" all of them react.

To be able to have mutliple loggers, make sure you provide them with different names, e.g., using your "path" variable.

Or for example:

```
class Logger(object):
def __init__(self, path='test',title=None):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(path + title)
    [...]
```